# Foobar - How to exclude non-music files?

Tags: audio, file-format, foobar2000

I drop my "Music" folder to foobar2000, all songs are included in the playlist, but also the other files (like album-art.jpg) are also included. When I'm shuffling, those files appear on the list and I get the error:

**Playback Error**

```
Unable to open item for playback (Unsupported file format):
"C:\Müzik\AlbumArt_{0CB8710B-C65E-4F4F-9603-26CAB3E10B3D}_Small.jpg"
```

So how can I tell foobar to include only sound files?

P.S.:
And if this is not the right place to ask such questions, please tell me where is.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in foobar2000 1.2. What version are you running?

Comment: @AaronMiller I use v1.2.3, in Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @void: Cannot reproduce either using fb2k 1.2.6 on Win7/8 x64, so my guess is it's either a misconfigured or buggy component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this either, but the relevant settings can be found in File > Preferences > Shell Integration. Set "Exclude file types" to "*.jpg" OR set "Restrict incoming files to" to something like "*.mp3;*.flac".